# How to get mac address for an interface in linux using a C Program?

Tags: c, linux

i want to find the mac address using a C program in linux. how to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1 minute of searching throug google: (i haven't tested it myself, i'm working on a windows machine in the moment)

```
/*
 * gethwaddr.c
 *
 * Demonstrates retrieving hardware address of adapter using ioctl()
 *
 * Author: Ben Menking <bmenking@highstream.net>
 *
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>    
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int s;
    struct ifreq buffer;

    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    memset(&buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));

    strcpy(buffer.ifr_name, "eth0");

    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &buffer);

    close(s);

    for( s = 0; s < 6; s++ )
    {
        printf("%.2X ", (unsigned char)buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[s]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anyway to get it without hardcoding "eth0"??

Comment: You have to assign a network adapter, otherwise there is no mac address, you could do it by input or as argument, but you're going to need an adapter.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great library to manage ethernet.
If You want go to low level stuff its certainly worth to learn.
It's quite hard C API to learn.

Lib PCAP.

[link to lib pcap sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpcap/)

Some sample code:

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>

void find_eth_addr(struct in_addr *search_ip, const struct pcap_pkthdr* pkthdr, const u_char *packet) {
struct ether_header *eth_hdr = (struct ether_header *)packet;

if (ntohs(eth_hdr->ether_type) == ETHERTYPE_IP) {
    struct ip *ip_hdr = (struct ip *)(packet + sizeof(struct ether_header));
if (ip_hdr->ip_dst.s_addr == search_ip->s_addr)
    print_eth_addr(eth_hdr->ether_dhost);
if (ip_hdr->ip_src.s_addr == search_ip->s_addr)
    print_eth_addr(eth_hdr->ether_shost);

}
}
```

There's also nice "kernel functions wrapper" like library:
**DNET**

which provides great functionality to use it on low level networking.
(also getting MAC addresses).

[DNET](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/dnet.3.txt)

There are UNIX & win ports for both libraries.